# gpgme: cache passphrase for symmetric encryption

Tags: c, encryption, gnupg, gpgme

I use `gpgme` library to encrypt several files symmetrically. They are encrypted with the same key (because of the same passphrase).

Is it possible to cache passphrase for a chain of encryption and decryption operations? I.e. I don't want to derive the same key again and again, if I'm able to perform multiple operations on it consequently.

I haven't found any of such possibility, but I suppose, that there could be a tricky way to do it.